# how to set a selected text with a inline <span> class?

Tags: quill

I would like to wrap a text with .
I've attempted to do it via extending the Inline class. 
i.e.

```
class MBlot extends Inline { }
MBlot.blotName = 'ql-important';
MBlot.tagName = 'span';
MBlot.className = 'important'
Quill.register(MBlot)
Quill.formatText(0, 5, 'ql-important', true);
```

However, this has no effect. 
BTW: If i change the tagName to "someOtherTag", it seems to work

How should i go about it?